# Cannot connect to the Maven process. Try again later. If the problem persists, check the Maven Importing JDK settings and restart IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I'm trying to add a new dependency in pom.xml in IntelliJ IDEA. After updating the pom.xml file, I right-clicked the file and selected:
Maven-> Reload project

Then it shows many errors in the Build->Sync tab:

> Cannot connect to the Maven process. Try again later. If the problem
> persists, check the Maven Importing JDK settings and restart IntelliJ
> IDEA

Does anyone know how to fix this error? I tried restarting Intellij but didn't help.

Comment: See https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/360014262940-Unable-to-import-Maven-project-import-fails-with-error-Cannot-reconnect

Comment: Also: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-273968/Cannot-connect-to-the-Maven-process One possible workaround mentioned is to change the JDK for Importer, preferably to a more up-to-date version.

Answer (score 2):

To fix it, we switch from the default "Bundled Maven 3" option to the manually installed Maven path.

In IntelliJ IDEA, click Preferences, Build Tools -> Maven

[The Solution from here](https://mkyong.com/intellij/intellij-idea-cannot-connect-to-the-maven-process/)

Answer (score 2):

"Maven" -> "Reload project" cleared the issue for me, without any IntelliJ configuration changes.

Comment: "Cannot reconnect". The problem came out of nowhere

Answer (score 0):

maybe is your hosts problem, you can edit the hosts file to

> 127.0.0.1 localhost

see [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/troubleshooting-common-maven-issues.html#e9e94f41).
it works to me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to Files -> Settings and follow the steps in the screenshot and set the Maven home path from Bundled Maven 3 to your installed maven

[Maven Home Path Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lmOxo.png)

Answer (score 0):

Only thing that helped me was to select option "Use Maven wrapper" in File->Settings->Build,Execution,Deployment->Maven->Maven Home Path

After Apply project reloaded and then I could return Maven Home Path to old value and it worked